# Certain functions are undefined when called form mu-plugins folder

Tags: wordpress

I have a correctly formatted php functions file in my mu-plugins/ directory.
When trying to use wp_is_mobile() or current_user_can(), I get an undefined function error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_is_mobile() in /var/www/dev.example.com/public/wp-content/mu-plugins/multisite-functions.php on line 147
```

Are certain core functions defined after the mu-plugins?
How do I fix or avoid this?
Can I simply not use certain functions in mu plugins?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WP cycle `vars.php` is included after `muplugins_loaded` fires ([link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-settings.php#L202)).

You should use `wp_is_mobile()` and the like **inside** wrapper functions that are hooked into `plugins_loaded` or `init`.

Comment: Bingo, thanksamundo @diggy, you've fixed my problem.